# How can i remove all string that listed on a list of strings, but only the one that followed by space

Tags: python, regex

I just started learning python and I'm currently trying to remove all of these strings :

```
removeThis = "dr|prof|mr|mrs"
```

but only the one that followed by space

```
removed = re.sub(removeThis, ' ', names)
```

I don't want it to remove the one that are in the middle of a string, how can i do this? Any help will be appreciated thank you!

Here the output im looking for, im trying to get only the names from the given input without any titles of the person:

```
#from
names = "Prof. Dr. Testdring Test"
#to : tesdrting test
```

Comment: Can you include sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: You can enclose it inside `\b`: `\b(?:dr|prof|mr|mrs)\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what you really want here is to use word boundaries in the regex:

```
input = "Prof. Dr. Testdring Test"
output = re.sub(r'\b(?:dr|prof|mr|mrs)\.(?=\s|$)', " ", input, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Testdring Test
```